# bootstrap 4 carousel resizing images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code here, Currently my carousel's images span over the entire screen, I want to make it short in height and width and the images remaining responsive. How can I achieve this effect. And I am using bootstrap 4, just to clear it out.

```
    <style>


.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: block;
}

    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="container-fluid">

    <nav style="border:1px solid black;">
      Navigation Space
    </nav>

                                                    <!--CAROUSEL-->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!--Wrapper for Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="images/car1.jpeg" alt="car1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Making Data Available</h3>
        <p>With 100% Accuracy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/car2.jpeg" alt="car2" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/car3.jpeg" alt="car3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Left and Right Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Post this code in fiddle and share the link :)

Comment: Can't produce the required link, it is just without the code.

Comment: try to put in jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap/
No use, it does not have the code.